# Avoid trigger while sending mail from apex in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger to blacklist some domain name while we are sending mail from salesforce.i just want to avoid trigger while we are sending mail using apex. So is it possible to do?
my trigger is below:

```
trigger BlackListEmailAddress on EmailMessage (before insert) {
     for(EmailMessage message: Trigger.New) {
        if(    (message.ToAddress.contains('gmail'))
            && message.Incoming==false){
            message.addError(  'Email Alert: You have selected a receipient email'
                             + ' from one of the blacklisted doamins please use another email address and try again');
        }
        if(    message.ToAddress.contains('yahoo')
            && message.Incoming==false) {
            message.addError(  'Email Alert: You have selected a receipient email from one ' 
                             + 'of the blacklisted doamins please use another email address and try again');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Idea is to use static variable when email is send from apex, and check that variable in this trigger. Execution context would be the same, so you can disable this when needed

Comment: How is your email class called? Are you calling it from visualforce pages? If so, you could use validation rules instead, but you'd need to put them on each object/page that calls your email class. Another option would be to add this method to your email class and you'd still be able to disable the method via a static boolean when desired.

Comment: an alternative is to have apex outbound email use a certain bcc address that you can detect on the `EmailMessage` itself. That said, this trigger will break if you implement things like `Email2Case` and you are auto-responding or otherwise replying to a Case coming from *.yahoo.com or *.gmail.com